# Unable to parse JSON string containing unicode hex character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```js
var mystring = '{"Customers":[{"CustomerCity":"Zaragoza","CustomerFName":"Ana","CustomerAddress":"C&#47; El Temple, 9 2\\xbaB","CustomerCountry":"es"}]}';

var myparsestring = JSON.parse(mystring);
```

**Error:**

> Unexpected token x in JSON

Comment: Your JSON isn't encoded properly

Comment: var mystring = '{"Customers":[{"CustomerCity":"Zaragoza","CustomerFName":"Ana","CustomerAddress":"C&#47; El Temple, 9 2/\/\xbaB","CustomerCountry":"es"}]}';

var myparsestring = JSON.parse(mystring);

Comment: I have escaped special characters to get it parsed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's simply invalid JSON, see the rules for strings [on json.org](http://json.org). There is no `\x` escape in JSON. The `\xbaB` should be a unicode escape, `\u0baB` (note that there must be exactly four hex digits):

```js
var mystring ='{"Customers":[{"CustomerCity":"Zaragoza","CustomerFName":"Ana","CustomerAddress":"C&#47; El Temple, 9 2\\u0baB","CustomerCountry":"es"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(mystring);
console.log(obj);
```

You could try to pre-process the string:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/\\x([0-9a-f]{1,4})/gi, function(m, c0) {
    return "\\u" + ("0000" + c0).slice(-4);
});
```

```js
var mystring ='{"Customers":[{"CustomerCity":"Zaragoza","CustomerFName":"Ana","CustomerAddress":"C&#47; El Temple, 9 2\\xbaB","CustomerCountry":"es"}]}';

// Fixing it
mystring = mystring.replace(/\\x([0-9a-f]{1,4})/gi, function(m, c0) {
    return "\\u" + ("0000" + c0).slice(-4);
});

var obj = JSON.parse(mystring);
console.log(obj);
```

...but really, it would be **much** better to fix the source of the JSON so it produces valid JSON, and the above is a very naïve fix.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder Your pre-process string worked for me.
I could not fix the source as am receiving it from the third party API.

Comment: @Sarang: I'm glad to hear that, but beware, if the source of that string is producing `\x` sequences, it may well do *other* invalid things. The fix really is to fix the source, not to patch up the string after.